# Installing python module "rpy2" after installing Enthought Canopy

Tags: python, r, rpy2, enthought

Some of my python scripts use rpy2 as an interface to R, which worked perfectly with the previous Enthought EPD python.

I recently installed Canopy Python from Enthought.
Python now no longer finds the rpy2 module, and when I try to reinstall it, I get the following errors:

```
$ easy_install rpy2

[...]

Processing rpy2-2.3.5.tar.gz
Writing /var/folders/9n/qk8wf11d205b0lrr57wyg7k80000gp/T/easy_install-HIclIh/rpy2-2.3.5/setup.cfg
Running rpy2-2.3.5/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/9n/qk8wf11d205b0lrr57wyg7k80000gp/T/easy_install-HIclIh/rpy2-2.3.5/egg-dist-tmp-A3O60G
"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 142: make: command not found
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/config: line 143: make: command not found
R was not built as a library
Invalid substring

in string

error: Setup script exited with Problem while running `"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error implies that R was not built with --enable-R-shlib or that the setup is having difficulty finding R.  Did you also upgrade/reinstall/rebuild R somewhere in this process?  At Terminal what is the output of the following commands:

```
echo $R_HOME
```

and

```
ls $R_HOME/lib
```

Presumably the first shows /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources which matches where the rpy install is looking, but do you have libR.dylib available in the second?

If not, have you tried reinstalling R?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It turned out that I had to rebuild R, and for this I had to download Xcode command line tools. Here's what solved the problem:1. Download newest version of Xcode (4.6.2)

2. In XCode Preferences > Downloads > Install Command line tools

3. Download newest version of R

4. in R-3.0.0 folder: ./configure --enable-R-shlib

5. easy_install rpy2