# Unable to configure rpy2 on ubuntu

Tags: python, r, ubuntu, rpy2, ldflags

I am new to this forum and its my first question. I am stuck with a task to configure a pipeline on a machine running Ubuntu 12.04 and few of the requirements for this are R version > 3, rpy2. I have been trying to configure rpy2 package. It comes up with this error message.

```
running build_ext
"/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags
R was not built as a library
Invalid substring
in string
```

Problem while running:

```
"/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
"/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags
R was not built as a library
Invalid substring
in string
```

Problem while running:

```
"/usr/local/lib64/R/bin/R" CMD config --ldflags
```

I have tried following [Installing python module "rpy2" after installing Enthought Canopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204246/installing-python-module-rpy2-after-installing-enthought-canopy) but even that did not work.

I am running R version 3.0.1 and python 2.7.3.
I have tried installing python3 as well. Have tried recompiling R. But they dot seem to work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The key part in the error message is:

```
R was not built as a library
```

This [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224871/installing-the-r-interpeter-and-r-as-a-shared-library-uder-the-same-tree) might be worth a look.